# Двойное хэширование MD5

Tags: c#, md5

Делаю авторизацию в приложении. На сайте пароль дважды шифруется MD5. Пытаюсь сделать двойное хэширование в `VS` - вроде бы и работает, но второй раз хэширует не правильно. Что подскажете?

```
MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
string pass = this.textBox2.Text;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {
      byte[] checkSum = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass));
      string result = BitConverter.ToString(checkSum).Replace("-", String.Empty);
      pass = result;
}
```

Comment: Что значит кодирует не правильно? Вы ждёте одного результата, а получаете другой?

Comment: Да, сверил с тем что получилось при регистрации на сайте, сверил на онлайн кодировщике MD5. Первый круг проходит верно, а второй уже нет.

Comment: В онлайн кодировщике вы тоже дефисы убираете?

Comment: Да, в онлайн тоже

Comment: В принципе самое главное, чтобы ваш метод при одних и тех же данных всегда выдавал один и тот же результат

Comment: Да, выдает одно и тоже, но к сожалению не то, что нужно

Comment: md5 - не шифрование, а хеширование. Возможно проблема с кодировкой

Comment: Тогда как объяснить что первый круг хэширует правильно?

Comment: бросьте сюда примеры - что на входе, что на выходе, в первом и втором случае

Comment: Попробуйте использовать не BitConverter.ToString, а Encoding.UTF8.GetString

Comment: Если не секрет, зачем вам хэш от хэша?

Comment: Решил проблему, убрав на сайте двойное хэширование

Comment: Хеширование с помощью одного-двух MD5 никак не защищает пароль, его очень легко можно узнать подбором

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошбика в том, что Вы не привели хэш к нижнему регистру.

```
void Main()
{
    var pass = "qwerty";
    var hash1 = Md5(pass);
    var hash2 = Md5(hash1);
    Console.WriteLine(hash1);
    Console.WriteLine(hash2);
}

static string Md5(string data)
{
    var provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    var hash = provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
    return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
}
```

Comment: Не согласен, нижний регистр не причем. Само значение хэша отличное от того, что получается на сайте

Comment: @g431k, а тут не надо соглашаться или не соглашаться, надо просто попробовать